# A questionnaire page with multi select dropdownlist in MVC5

Tags: multi-select, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to MVC, This might be simple but I've looked everywhere for a solution and no luck. My problem is that I have a page that will contain many drop down lists of lines and not just one word. The user must select at least one line or more from each list. when they hit submit, all the selected items need to populate either on a pdf or a blank pop up as TXT. I've looked into enums, select2, chosen, Bootstrap select... the project I'm adding this page in is MVC5 code first approach with a database of users, the users function is to have roles assigned for different questionnaire. any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!